# Hidden character Shift-Arrow Up-Backspace

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes when I want to delete a line of text very quickly I do this:

I hold the shift key and press the arrow up key to select the line above and then I press backspace. But occasionally I press all three keys at the same time which deletes the line too but creates a hidden control character with the value 08: the value for the backspace control character.

This can be pretty annoying e.g. if you are writing code and you can't figure out what causes the parse error.

Am I the only one who struggles with this from time to time? Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. I'm using a MacBook Pro (built-in keyboard) on Lion. Obviously I'm testing it in Chrome, and I tried in MacVim too.

(1) What is your hardware setup? (2) Which app(s?) can you do this in?

Comment: Can't reproduce either

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Chrome. I guess they disabled control characters. Try it in the search field in Safari. The X icon will appear, which proofs that there is invisible text.

Comment: Is "backspace" what my keyboard calls "delete"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace

Comment: What editor(s) can you get this to happen in? Perhaps its a feature that could be disabled.

Comment: Just try it in Safari as I wrote above. Its a bug or feature in Mac OS I guess since 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this either. However, I suggest that you hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> and then press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, as an alternative to your method. This will delete everything on the line that's left of the cursor, and will hopefully solve your problem. (You can hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> to delete single words. Experiment with holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> key, and pressing either <kbd>Delete</kbd> or the arrow keys. If you hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> with either <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> and then press the arrow keys, you will be able to select text word by word, or line by line.)